# Application of Vector Calculus;Line integrals

Tags: vector-analysis

A force is given by $\ F=(cxy \ i + x^6y^2\ j)$, where $i$ and $j$ are unit vectors.The force acts on a particle which must move from (0,0) to the line x=1 along the curve $y=a(x^b)$ where $a>0,b>0$. Find a value of $a$ in terms of $c$ such that the work done is independent of $b$.

Comment: What have you tried and/or where do you get stuck? Also: please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the mathematics in your question.

Comment: i cannot approach this problem i want to know how to evaluate line integral along a curve

Comment: Parametrize the curve by a function $\vec \gamma: I\subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ where $I=[a,b]$ for some $a<b\in \Bbb R$.  Then the work done by the force is given by $$W = \int_a^b \vec F(\vec \gamma(t))\cdot \vec \gamma'(t)dt$$

Comment: what will be the parametric equation

Comment: How about $\vec \gamma(t) = (t, at^b), \quad t\in \Bbb R$?

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of work
$$\begin {align}W &= \int F\cdot dr \\
 &= \int (cxy\ \hat{i} + x^6y^2\ \hat{j})\cdot(dx \ \hat{i} + dy\ \hat{j}) \\
 &= \int cxy \ dx + x^6y^2\ dy 
\end{align}$$
You are given a curve $y = ax^b$ along which the particle moves. Use this to evaluate the integral.

(Substitute $y = ax^b$, $dy = ab\ x^{b-1} dx$)

$$\begin {align}
W = \int_0^1 ac\ x^{b+1}\ dx + \int_0^1 ab \ x^{b+5} \ dx
\end{align}$$